# How can I solve these two rotation along the x-axis questions?

Tags: math, calculus, x-axis

Question 1

A) Find the volume V of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified line. y=5 sqrt(25-x^2), y = 0, x = 1, x = 4; about the x-axis with a sketch of the region/solid form (include disk rotation as well)

B)Find the volume V of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified line.y = (1/25)x^2,  x = 5,  y = 0; about the x-axis with a sketch of the region/solid form (include disk rotation as well)

Comment: I think you might want to post it in the maths( https://math.stackexchange.com/) forum instead of down here... here we are look at code

Comment: This is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow, which is for programming questions. Consider posting instead to https://math.stackexchange.com/.